# sql server - Google maps api returns too much data

Tags: sql-server-2005, google-maps-api-3

Im using sql server to call out to the google maps api and get data for a gps location. It worked fine but lately my stored procedure that calls out fails with this error

```
0x8004271F 
ODSOLE Extended Procedure 
The source data specified for this string or binary column or parameter is too long.
```

It seems that the character limit is being reached when google returns a "boat load" of location data.

This is what Im calling out with so far:

```
-- Select dbo.fnGetAddressFromGPS('33.83528299,-118.28754585')  

-- -- GO
Declare @GPS VarChar(50)
Set @GPS = '34.55,-118.50'
DECLARE @URL VarChar(4000)
DECLARE @win int 
DECLARE @hr  int 
DECLARE @text varchar(8000)

Set @URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=' + @GPS + '&sensor=false'


Set @URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=34.5566767,-118.50677688&sensor=false'
Set @URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?  latlng=34.5566767,-118.50677688&sensor=false'

EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1',@win OUT 
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open',NULL,'GET',@url,'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win,'Send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText',@text OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @win 
--IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 



Select @Text As 'GoogleResult'
Return



IF CHARINDEX('ZERO_RESULTS', @text) > 0
Select 'No Address Found'


Declare @i Int
Declare @j Int
Declare @Address VarChar(150)

SELECT @i = CHARINDEX('<formatted_address>', @Text);
SELECT @j = CHARINDEX('</formatted_address>', @Text);

SELECT @i = CHARINDEX('"formatted_address" : "', @Text);
Select @i
Return


If @j-@i-Len('<formatted_address>') <= 0 
Select @Address = 'N/A'
Else
Select @Address = SubString(@text, @i+Len('<formatted_address>'), @j-@i-    Len('<formatted_address>'))

--Select @Address

Select @Address
```

What I would like to do is limit the returning data from google to only the formatted address portion which is all I really need but I havent found anywhere in the documenation on how to do such a thing. The only other thing I can think of doing is truncating the result data but I cant figure that out either at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what about varchar(max)?

Comment: That wont work as I cant get the text out of the response.

Comment: @ScottE has a good point.  Can you run it with `DECLARE @text varchar(MAX)`?

Comment: provide the lat/lon that causes the error.

Comment: No whats happening is that EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText',@text OUTPUT is failing because it runs into a limit at 8000 characters. Thats what Im trying to work around. Without getting the data out first using some other method which I dont know about and cant find it wouldnt matter how big I made the varchar

Answer (score 3):

The interesting part here is inserting into a table:

DECLARE @resTbl  AS TABLE (result NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT @resTbl EXEC @HttpWinRequest=sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText'

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_http_get
    /*
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
*/
    @url VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @win int, @HttpWinRequest  int

DECLARE @resTbl  AS TABLE (result NVARCHAR(MAX))



EXEC @HttpWinRequest=sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1',@win OUT

IF @HttpWinRequest <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win
EXEC @HttpWinRequest=sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open',NULL,'GET',@url,'false'

IF @HttpWinRequest <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win EXEC @HttpWinRequest=sp_OAMethod @win,'Send'


IF @HttpWinRequest <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

INSERT @resTbl EXEC @HttpWinRequest=sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText'

IF @HttpWinRequest <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win
EXEC @HttpWinRequest=sp_OADestroy @win

IF @HttpWinRequest <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

SELECT * FROM @resTbl
END
GO

EXEC usp_http_get @url = 'http://www.yahoo.com' -- varchar(8000)
```